# Optimize duplicate integers in list / DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to get "*Expected list*" from "*Original list*" in Python 3 or by using Pandas?

Original list:

```
array = [1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 20213, 22170, 22170, ...]
```

Expected list:

```
array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, ...]
```

*Duplicated integers are needed and cannot be removed as they represent id.*

Comment: How are you getting from one list to the other?

Comment: You could use `pd.factorize(array)[0] + 1`... ? That'll give you a numpy array

Comment: Do you want to sort your list? Or map?

Comment: is it a sorted list?

Comment: @enke is not sorted.

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha no.

Comment: @JonClements thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've found a Pandas solution. Here's a pure Python attempt:

```
array = [1, 1, 5, 8, 8, 20213, 22170, 22170]

position = {}
result = [position.setdefault(item, len(position) + 1) for item in array]
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Or a bit more efficient:

```
position = {}
result = [
    position[item] if item in position
    else position.setdefault(item, len(position) + 1)
    for item in array
]
```